# What papyrus is this?

Tags: sappho, passage-identification, papyrology

[image]

The image shows two papyrus fragments, and seems to suggest they should join as placed, perhaps with some space in between. In fact, it seems there is sellotape putting them together.

The bigger fragment on the left is P.Oxy. 1787 fr. 4, which is the source for Sappho Lobel-Page 65, given by Campbell as follows:

[image]

The other fragment I cannot seem to identify. To my eyes, it reads:

> ]MNĀ . [
>   ] . KAN̤T€Ι[
>   ] . Ϲ̣Ḳ[

Can anyone help me identify this, and figure out why it's placed with fr. 4?
UPDATE

I've identified the papyrus, but the reason for the joint is still unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually LP 66(c), from a papyrus published directly in Lobel's Σαπφοῦς μελῶν. From LP's text and notes, we get his transcription as follows:

> ]MNĀ[
>   ] . ΚΑΤ̣€Γ[
>   ]Ḳ€Κ[

Where some options for the vestige in l. 2 are ινρ and l. 3 could end in a nu or lambda too. To reconcile my transcription with his:

- I see now I missed the top of the gamma in l. 2, which is therefore certain as in LP;
- I seem to have read my AN in what was actually just an alpha with some bad fading;
- I'm still convinced the tau is certain in l. 2, I really don't see what else it could be;
- L. 3 starts with traces that could form a K, but also a chi IMO, so I leave the vestige;
- I see absolutely no reason to make that a certain epsilon, though of course it's a possible choice, and given my choice of sigma would very likely lead to three consonants in a row, which is not a thing in Greek, I change to uncertain epsilon.

So I revise my transcription as follows:

> ]MNĀ[
>   ] . ΚΑT€Γ[
>   ] . €̣Κ[

As for why they join, LP says «e regione 65 vv. 6-8 collocandum esse liquet», «is clearly to be collocated in the region of ll. 6-8 of fr. 65», and LP 65 is from the big fragment, so LP is convinced they go together, but doesn't explain why. So that question stays open.